# find html element, without proper class name or id, with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code

```
<div class="option-wrapper">
    <label class="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="1" data-type-xml="select" aria-label="Untitled">
        <span lang="" class="option-label active">1</span>
    </label>
    <label class="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="2" data-type-xml="select" aria-label="Untitled">
        <span lang="" class="option-label active">2</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

im trying to find the labels and to set a "style="display: none;"
like this `<label class="" style="display: none;>`

my problem is, I only need one of the labels in this div. But I don't have a class name or id to find one label. Do u guys know a solution for this?

Comment: Which one of the label you want set the display:none value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.getElementsByTagName('label')` instead for all end then get them with the array offset. Or - to select the first - use `document.getElementByTagName('label')`. Notice the singular version of the second selector.

Or, a more general selector which you can use with either classes or tags or any other query string would be `document.querySelector('label')` or `document.querySelectorAll('label')`